# calculating energy usage with measuring the temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, building-physics

I am an electrical engineer working on a project. My goal of this project is to make an IoT solution where I continuously measure the temperature of room in a building. I want to calculate the amount of energy used to heat or cool that room. Optionally I am going to measure multiple rooms in the same building. Which aspects or formulas of thermodynamics can I use to calculate the amount of energy used.

I have looked around and found one formula to calculate the estimated energy. I have found this website: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/heat-work-energy-d_292.html

$$Q = C_p m \Delta T$$

where:

- $Q$ is the amount of heat in [kJ];
- $C_p$, the specific heat in [kJ/kg K];
- $m$, the mass [kg];
- $\Delta T$, the temperature difference between hot and cold side [K].

My plan was to use this formula to calculate how much energy is needed to warm or cool the air in the room. Is there a better way to solve my problem or is this the only way possible?

Comment: I'd take a look at the ASHRAE Handbook, it might have some helpful information.

Comment: I suggest that monitoring the heating/cooling equipment is easier.

Answer (score 0):

This formula is the right way to calculate the energy consumption of the system, in your case - for warming or cooling the air in the room and the way to make it better is to find out how to accurately measure rooms average temperature and humidity of the air.

But you should to take in account that there are buildings heat transfer through walls, windows, vents and another construction elements and parts which is determined by energy efficiency of the building, and sometimes to warm/cool you don't need to spent energy at all or it will be greater then calculated.

Comment: you also have to heat up/cool down everything in the building, including the building itself.